# Moving back in dir not working in Eclipse under windows

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

In one of my Eclipse projects in WebContent section I have two folders one called "assets" and one called "dashboard". "Dashboard" contains a file errorlogs.html that calls css file in "assets". So I have to go back one dir and the get to assets, I'm usign href to do this but for some reason I cannot apply the css.  Here's my code in dashboard:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type'text/css" href="../assets/css/styles_main.css"/>
```

The only think I could think of is the problem has to do with using Eclipse and Windows7 since this works fine on Linux. Is there another syntax for doing this in Windows using Eclipse?

Comment: You can't move back beyond the application to root (and it shouldn't work on Linux either).

Comment: @developerwjk I am not moving beyond application, I have files in Eclipse, WebContent contains both assets and dashboard files I just want to go from dashboard to assets inside of WebC0ntent

Comment: In Firefox view source, click the link in the href there, and see if the css file opens. If it does, then the problem is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<link>` is a void element.It has no closing tag.
try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type'text/css" href="../assets/css/styles_main.css">
```